# How do i compare timestamps in google spreadsheets with a custom function or script?

Tags: google-sheets, sum, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, gs-vlookup

I have the following in google spreadsheets and i'm having trouble figuring out how to calculate some values and add them to a chart.  (this is just a sample, the full data set is very long!):

```
4:27:52 DraconicPiggy   Connected
5:01:01 Myshiro         Connected
5:03:08 deathweek       Connected
5:06:08 deathweek       Disconnected
5:09:05 mallacke        Connected
5:11:29 deathweek       Connected
5:11:37 deathweek       Disconnected
5:19:20 MobBosss        Connected
5:23:13 MobBosss        Disconnected
```

Ideally, what I would like to do is to compare the timestamps. But I have no clue where to start. It would go sort of like this: When there's a timestamp for 04:00:00, then a timestamp for 06:00:00, i want the value 02:00:00, or 2 hours to be stored somewhere, possibly in another column, comparing the 2 together. I don't want it to add time when the player is offline, so a way to ignore timestamps with disconnected would be ideal. Also a way to seperate the players and create new values for each player if its possible. I don't know if any of this is possible, so forgive me if it's not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(FILTER({B1:B, IFNA(VLOOKUP(
 B1:B&COUNTIFS(B1:B, B1:B, ROW(B1:B), "<="&ROW(B1:B), C1:C, "Connected"), FILTER({
 B1:B&COUNTIFS(B1:B, B1:B, ROW(B1:B), "<="&ROW(B1:B), C1:C, "Connected"), A1:A}, 
 C1:C="Disconnected"), 2, 0))-A1:A}, C1:C="Connected"))
```

[image]

---

if you want sum per unique player use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(FILTER({B1:B, TIMEVALUE(IFNA(VLOOKUP(
 B1:B&COUNTIFS(B1:B, B1:B, ROW(B1:B), "<="&ROW(B1:B), C1:C, "Connected"), FILTER({
 B1:B&COUNTIFS(B1:B, B1:B, ROW(B1:B), "<="&ROW(B1:B), C1:C, "Connected"), A1:A}, 
 C1:C="Disconnected"), 2, 0))-A1:A)}, C1:C="Connected"), 
 "select Col1,sum(Col2) group by Col1 label sum(Col2)'' format sum(Col2)'[hh]:mm:ss'", 0))
```

[image]